# Sample NSImage and retain quality (swift 3)

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I wrote an NSImage extension to allow me to take random samples of an image. I would like those samples to retain the same quality as the original image. However, they appear to be aliased or slightly blurry. Here's an example - the original drawn on the right and a random sample on the left:

[image: sample]

I'm playing around with this in SpriteKit at the moment. Here's how I create the original image:

```
    let bg = NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "ref")
    let tex = SKTexture(image: bg)
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y:size.height/2)
    addChild(sprite)
```

And here's how I create the sample:

```
    let sample = bg.sample(size: NSSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    let sampletex = SKTexture(image:sample!)
    let samplesprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:sampletex)
    samplesprite.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y:size.height/2)
    addChild(samplesprite)
```

Here's the NSImage extension (and randomNumber func) that creates the sample:

```
extension NSImage {

    /// Returns the height of the current image.
    var height: CGFloat {
        return self.size.height
    }

    /// Returns the width of the current image.
    var width: CGFloat {
        return self.size.width
    }

    func sample(size: NSSize) -> NSImage? {
        // Resize the current image, while preserving the aspect ratio.
        let source = self

        // Make sure that we are within a suitable range
        var checkedSize    = size
        checkedSize.width  = floor(min(checkedSize.width,source.size.width * 0.9))
        checkedSize.height = floor(min(checkedSize.height, source.size.height * 0.9))

        // Get random points for the crop.
        let x = randomNumber(range: 0...(Int(source.width) - Int(checkedSize.width)))
        let y = randomNumber(range: 0...(Int(source.height) - Int(checkedSize.height)))

        // Create the cropping frame.
        var frame = NSRect(x: x, y: y, width: Int(checkedSize.width), height: Int(checkedSize.height))

        // let ref = source.cgImage.cropping(to:frame)
        let ref = source.cgImage(forProposedRect: &frame, context: nil, hints: nil)
        let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: ref!)

        // Create a new image with the new size
        let img = NSImage(size: checkedSize)

        // Set a graphics context
        img.lockFocus()
        defer { img.unlockFocus() }

        // Fill in the sample image
        if rep.draw(in: NSMakeRect(0, 0, checkedSize.width, checkedSize.height),
                    from: frame,
                    operation: NSCompositingOperation.copy,
                    fraction: 1.0,
                    respectFlipped: false,
                    hints: [NSImageHintInterpolation:NSImageInterpolation.high.rawValue]) {
            // Return the cropped image.
            return img
        }

        // Return nil in case anything fails.
        return nil
    }

}

func randomNumber(range: ClosedRange<Int> = 0...100) -> Int {
    let min = range.lowerBound
    let max = range.upperBound
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(1 + max - min))) + min
}
```

I've tried this about 10 different ways and the results always seem to be a slightly blurry sample. I even checked for smudges on my screen. :)

How can I create a sample of an NSImage that retains the exact qualities of the section of the original source image?

Comment: Try `NSImageInterpolation.none`. Also, if `cgImage(forProposedRect:...)` changed the frame, then you should change the `in:` rect you draw to. You should basically use a copy of `frame` that's offset by (-x, -y) so it's relative to (0, 0) instead of (x, y).

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases! `NSImageInterpolation.none` did the trick. I think I had tried all the values other than that. If you want to add an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the interpolation mode to `NSImageInterpolation.none` was apparently sufficient in this case.

It's also important to handle the draw destination rect correctly.  Since `cgImage(forProposedRect:...)` may change the proposed rect, you should use a destination rect that's based on it. You should basically use a copy of `frame` that's offset by (-x, -y) so it's relative to (0, 0) instead of (x, y).